# pandas read_csv raises ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read txt data seperated by ',' and '\t', and I use code below:

`io_df = pd.read_csv('input_output.txt',sep='\D|\t',engine = 'python')`

This triggered error information below:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-5ab0138d93ac> in <module>()
----> 1 io_df = pd.read_csv('input_output.txt',sep='\D|\t',engine = 'python')`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

For me works `sep=",|\t"`:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=",|\t", engine = 'python')
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/test.csv',
                 sep=",|\t", 
                 engine = 'python')
print (df)

  col col1 col2
0   a    d    t
1   d    u    l
```

Comment: Thank you, it's Ok to solve this problem. But if I want to seperate by **regex** expression, it always raise error, how to solve?

Comment: It is very hard help you, because I have not your file.

Comment: I think the best is works with small file sample, try identify what causes error and then find solution.

Comment: And sometimes helps update `pandas` to last version.